# assign variable to list view label on databound

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to assign a string variable to a label inside a listview web control.

This is the code I have tried so far:

```
Public Sub lvRecipeSteps_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim strRecId As String = dvRecipeItem.DataKey.Value.ToString()
    CType(lvRecipeSteps.FindControl("lblRecId"), Label).Text = strRecId.ToString()
End Sub
```

Line:

```
    CType(lvRecipeSteps.FindControl("lblRecId"), Label).Text = strRecId.ToString()
```

returns error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is the label inside the listview:

```
            <asp:ListView 
            ID="lvRecipeSteps" 
            runat="server" 
            DataKeyNames="Id" 
            DataSourceID="EntityDataSource_RecipeSteps" 
            InsertItemPosition="LastItem"                
            ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder"
            OnDataBinding="lvRecipeSteps_DataBinding"
            OnDataBound="lvRecipeSteps_DataBound">                                
            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <tr style="background-color: whitesmoke;">
                    <td class="RefineRecipe_Steps_Cells">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" CausesValidation="False" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to edit this record?');"/>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" CausesValidation="False" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="RefineRecipe_Steps_Cells">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblRecId" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:Label></td>
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone please help offer a helping hand?

This is much appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

I changed to ItemDataBound

```
    Protected Sub lvRecipeSteps_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemEventArgs)

    Dim strRecId As String = dvRecipeItem.DataKey.Value.ToString()

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem Then
        Dim dataItem As ListViewDataItem = DirectCast(e.Item, ListViewDataItem)
        Dim tb_1 As Label = CType(lvRecipeSteps.FindControl("lblRecId"), Label)
        tb_1.Text = strRecId.ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

And I get an error: **object reference not set to an instance of an object**

Line: tb_1.Text = strRecId.ToString

**UPDATE 2**

I got it to work, somehow

```
    Protected Sub lvRecipeSteps_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemEventArgs)

    Dim strRecId As String = String.Empty
    Dim lblRecId As Label = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("Recipe_IdLabel"), Label)

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem Then
        Dim dataItem As ListViewDataItem = DirectCast(e.Item, ListViewDataItem)
        If e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem Then
            If Session("Id") IsNot Nothing Then
                strRecId = Session("Id")
            Else
                strRecId = dvRecipeItem.DataKey.Value.ToString()
            End If
            lblRecId.Text = strRecId.ToString()
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

the problem now is that when there are no children records (listview) for the record that is displayed on the detailsview, then the listview displays on insert template, but is not assignin the id of the detailsview record, and i need to id filled in the insert template too.

what do i need to add? any ideas?

thank you much for your help

**UPDATE 3**

I think I got it to work:

```
    Protected Sub lvRecipeSteps_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemEventArgs)

    Dim strRecId As String = String.Empty
    Dim lblRecId As Label = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("Recipe_IdLabel"), Label)

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem Then
        Dim dataItem As ListViewDataItem = DirectCast(e.Item, ListViewDataItem)
        If e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem Then
            If Session("Id") IsNot Nothing Then
                strRecId = Session("Id")
            Else
                strRecId = dvRecipeItem.DataKey.Value.ToString()
            End If
            lblRecId.Text = strRecId.ToString()
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all to set value of a label in the list view item on data bound, you need to use ItemDataBound event, not DataBound event. Then you get the event triggered for each item's data bound.
Also check both ItemTemplate and AlternatingItemTemplate has the label lblRecId. If you have HeaderTemplate and FooterTemplate then you need to make sure you run the Line of code only if the following condition is true

```
e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon Kiran Hegde's answer and your own update, you need to find the lblRecId control within a ListViewDataItem, not the entire ListView. Since the ListView could potentially have multiple ListViewDataItems, it could also have multiple lblRecIds. Specifying the ListViewDataItem you want to find the label in should get you where you want to be.

```
Dim tb_1 As Label = CType(dataItem.FindControl("lblRecId"), Label)
```